# how to get http://localhost:3000 dynamic

Tags: node.js, express

I want to set link in my header file like this :

```
<ul class="header">
  <li><a href="/">Index</a></li>  
  <li><a href="client-list">client-List</a></li>  
  <li><a href="client-add">client-Add</a></li>  
  <li><a href="about-us">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

but it gives me error sometimes because it is not full path , how can i add this

```
<ul class="header">
  <li><a href="localhost:3000/">Index</a></li>    
  </ul>
```

Comment: set a variable in node.js @ server side and get it in your template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add protocol http:// before localhost.